# Spark Streaming with Kafka - Messages not printing to console

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

I am using the following code to consume and print messages from kafka. However, the messages are not printing. I can confirm that the issue is not with Kafka. How do you print the messages?

```
package com.paras.KafkaSpark
import java.util.HashMap
import java.util.Properties
import kafka.serializer.StringDecoder
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.{KafkaProducer, ProducerConfig, ProducerRecord}
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.streaming._
import org.apache.spark.streaming.kafka._



object StreamKafkaLearn {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 4) {
      System.err.println("Usage: KafkaWordCount <zkQuorum> <group> <topics> <numThreads>")
     System.exit(1)
    }

    val Array(zkQuorum, group, topics, numThreads) = args

    // Create context with 2 second batch interval
    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("DirectKafkaTest")
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(2))

    // Create direct kafka stream with brokers and topics
    val topicMap = topics.split(",").map((_, numThreads.toInt)).toMap
    val lines = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, group, topicMap).map(_._2)

    // Get the lines, split them into words, count the words and print
    //lines.print()

   lines.foreachRDD{ rdd =>
      val testString = rdd.collect()
      println(testString.mkString("\n")) // prints to the stdout of the driver
      }


      ssc.start()
      ssc.awaitTermination()
      }
}
```

Comment: This is the output:


    16/09/05 19:20:32 INFO yarn.Client: Application report for application_1466798156891_0141 (state: RUNNING)

Comment: You can not print the message using println while running application in yarn cluster mode. Instead of doing like this, you can use some logger, and run application in yarn client mode. You will get the log on your master console.

Comment: In addition to Abhi's comment, foreachRDD runs your code on the executor, so it would be printed on the executor machine.  Check the stdout logs of the executor.